# Enabling memory cgroup in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubernetes

Instructions for enabling the memory cgroup on Ubuntu 18 and 19 involve adding `cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1` to `/boot/firmware/nobtcmd.txt` and restarting.  After rebooting, `grep mem /proc/cgroups` should show it as enabled.

I find that on Ubuntu 20.04 the above instructions are not working for me, and Kubernetes continues to error `[ERROR SystemVerification]: missing cgroups: memory`.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

I was able to get this working by appending `cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1` to the file `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt`.  Changes made to `/boot/firmware/nobtcmd.txt` in Ubuntu 20.04 appear to be ignored (there's a note in config.txt about cmdline=nobtcmd.txt being deprecated in favour of include commands).

Comment: Thanks can confirm, this actually works on 20.04

Answer (score 5):

On 22.04 (kernel 5.15.0) booting via Grub:

- add `cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1` to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in `/etc/default/grub`;
- followed by `sudo update-grub` and kernel reboot.

Verify with **`cat /proc/cmdline`**.

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1 systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0" [issue](https://github.com/canonical/microk8s/issues/1691)

Comment: After upgrade to 22.04, Docker failed to start complaining about "Your kernel does not support cgroup memory limit". This fixed it.