# How to set cgroup_memory=enable on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: 21.10, cgroup

I have seen evidence to suggest that on Ubuntu 20.04 you add this line to /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt per [Enabling memory cgroup in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237813/enabling-memory-cgroup-in-ubuntu-20-04), however I have a /boot directory but not /boot/firmware, so where should I specify this for Ubuntu 21.10 ?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to this here: [How to run cgexec without sudo as current user on Ubuntu 22.04 with cgroups v2, failing with "cgroup change of group failed"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406329/how-to-run-cgexec-without-sudo-as-current-user-on-ubuntu-22-04-with-cgroups-v2)

I tested this on a x86_64 device running Ubuntu 22.04.:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

# Edit this line like so:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false"

sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

A note to anyone enabling cgroups for AWS Greengrass:
Edit `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` to be:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1 systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
```